# Python regular expression for postgresql query reading from database

Tags: python, regex

I want to make some regular expression in Python for detecting when a query is returning some data or not. Until recently I had this:

```
SQL_QUERY_REGEX = re.compile(rb'(?:^\s*SELECT)|RETURNING',  re.IGNORECASE)
```

but right now I realized this fails when a query having a WITH clause appears, so I need now a more complex regex, so I tried this:

```
SQL_QUERY_REGEX = re.compile(rb'(?:^\s*(?:WITH)?.*SELECT)|RETURNING',  re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
```

but this would fail with an INSERT having a previous WITH clause defined.

My last try (only regex, for abbreviating) is:

```
(?P<with>WITH.*as.*\([\s]*SELECT[\s\S]*FROM[\s\S]*\))?(?:(?P<insert>INSERT INTO [\S\s]*RETURNING.*)|(?P<select>SELECT[\s\S]*FROM[\s\S]*))
```

So, my expected regular expression would have this as input:

```
WITH thing as(
    SELECT field
    FROM table1
    WHERE field2 > 10
)
SELECT field   -- I want to know there is a SELECT returning data to python from here!
FROM thing t
NATURAL JOIN mytable t2
WHERE t2.field2 = 15
```

and detect the "SELECT field FROM thing..." substring so that we know this query will return something. **But all my regexes catch everything from the first SELECT not the last one**.

Also it should catch similar INSERTs like:

```
INSERT INTO sometable(f1, f2) VALUES
WITH thing as(
    SELECT field, field2
    FROM table1
    WHERE field2 > 10
)
SELECT field, field2
FROM thing t
NATURAL JOIN mytable t2
WHERE t2.condition_field = 15
RETURNING field  -- I want to detect this RETURNING, meaning some data is going to the python code
```

and detect there is a RETURNING at the end, but it shouldn't validate with just a SELECT in an INSERT or the WITH previous to INSERT. I suppose the same is applicable for UPDATEs.

So I don't know what's wrong. I tried non-greedy quantifiers (*?) with no success. I'd like some guidance before just using lookbehinds and lookaheads like a crazy person (also not much experience with those).

Comment: `[\s\S]*` is too greedy. You might want to temper it to some extent, like `(?:(?!\bSELECT\b)[\s\S])*`, but it is still fragile since parsing SQL with regex is generally very fragile.

Comment: I agree with @WiktorStribiżew, when you find yourself writing more and more complex queries, you're in muddy territory.  Why do you need to find out pre-execution, whether a query will return something? How are the queries constructed? Can you describe a general form that you need to capture with regexes? I would try to answer these questions

Comment: I know it is somewhat fragile, but making a parser from scratch with no experience is no better. Also, I only want to know if the current query is returning some data to Python and I need to process it or not.

Comment: Also, as long as I understand the problem, I only need to know if there is some data coming back from database, so I don't need to detect any details in FROM clauses or if there is a WHERE/HAVING/GROUPBY clause or not

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm doing this post-execution and only if there is some data returned by the query/statement, I'm processing it

Comment: In fact, writing a parser makes much more sense than fiddling around with regex. You already have an unreadable and very inefficient pattern. You could throw in some recursion with PyPi regex module, but I am pretty much sure it will bring you nowhere. Just been there myself.

Comment: Would learning how to do a parser take much time? Or can I find a good existing parser I can use for this purpose?

Comment: The reason I asked if you have a general pattern of what to look for, is that you can maybe write a stupid regex. But this is going to break if you aren't always fetching the same queries. I'm going to see what I can do.

Since you're doing it post-execution, can't you just check if the query returned something?

Comment: Somebody has likely done the effort of writing a grammar for SQL in Python. Not sure of one however.

Comment: I'm adding every now and then new queries. No general pattern, because this depends on new functionalities from the customer. Also, yes I was checking in my psycopg2 code  with `cursor.rowcount > 0` but that wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To match only non-nested selects, we use a negative lookahead for a closing parenthesis `)`

   - `SELECT(?!.*\))`
2. Finding the optional return should be easy.

Be sure to use a single-line (dotall) flag, or alternatively strip all newlines as this answer previously said.

```py
x.replace(\n, '')
```

I have marked the captured expressions inside `[]`

```sql
WITH thing as
(
  SELECT field
  FROM table1
  WHERE field2 > 10
)
[SELECT] field
FROM thing t
NATURAL JOIN mytable t2
WHERE t2.field2 =
```

```sql
INSERT INTO sometable(f1, f2) VALUES
WITH thing as
(
  SELECT field, field2
  FROM table1
  WHERE field2 > 10
)
[SELECT] field, field2
FROM thing t
NATURAL JOIN mytable t2
WHERE t2.condition_field = 15
[RETURNING] field
```

I am warning again, that this is a bad idea, if you cannot guarantee the general pattern of your queries. The key thing is that you're only going to know if the `SELECT` you're matching is not followed by a close parenthesis at any point.

Comment: Is not possible to use the negative lookahead in multiline mode?

Comment: Please see the updated answer for a simple solution. But generally no, I tested with https://regexr.com/ and it seems look-ahead and look-behind strictly works on a line by line basis.

Comment: Lookarounds have nothing to do with matching multiline texts. @madtyn Parsing SQL with regex is like parsing XML with regex. No go.

Comment: That's actually correct, a dotall flag is really equivalent, I have updated the answer. But while parsing SQL with regex is a no-go, OP here is only looking for a select that isn't in a subquery and has its value returned.